# Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: Win32 error 127 - even when importing self process

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, dynamic-linking, node-ffi

The most basic example in node Foreign Function Interface is calling `atoi` by loading it from node's own process:

```
var ffi = require('ffi');

var current = ffi.Library(null, {
  'atoi': [ 'int', [ 'string' ] ]
});
console.log(typeof current.atoi('1234')); // 1234
```

But I get this error:

```
    throw new Error('Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: ' + this.error())
    ^

Error: Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: Win32 error 127
    at DynamicLibrary.get (D:\web\node_modules\ffi\lib\dynamic_library.js:112:11)
    at D:\web\node_modules\ffi\lib\library.js:50:19
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.Library (D:\web\node_modules\ffi\lib\library.js:47:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\web\native\winapi.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
```

Clearly it cannot be related to the 32/64bit incompatibility since I'm accessing my own process. So what's wrong exactly?

- Platform: Windows 7x64
- Node: v6.2.2
- ffi: 2.2.0
- ref: 1.3.3

Answer (score 0):

The first param to ffi.library should be the name of dll you are trying to load, the error you have encountered relates to a missing symbol.

Comment: According to the docs, passing null means you're linking functions from your own process.

Comment: That error could also relate to calling a 32bit symbol especially if you are not loading the library yourself.

Comment: Sure, but I assumed that loading symbols from currently running binary should not lead to x64 vs x32 conflict. It's written in the question btw.

Comment: It could also be any dependency the symbol may have

Comment: Well, sure, but this was the basic example on the project website. I tried few more things and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio uses cpp compile default, try to wrap your dll function with "extern c", eg:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    __declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

BTW, a correct example of ffi:

Firstly, install ffi and node-gpy package
Then, in your js code:

```
const ffi = require('ffi');
var libm = ffi.Library(__dirname + '/dll/add.dll', {
    'add': ['int', ['int', 'int']]
});

console.log(libm.add(1,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I also encountered an error loading DLL using node-ffi. My solution is: 1. Whether the introduced DLL supports current computer systems such as 64-bit or 32-bit. I made this mistake before, when I converted the DLL file to 64 bits, the problem was solved!